# how to export ADO.net entity data model to a .mdf file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, mdf

I've created my first ADO.net entity data model.
In it there are 2 tables (with no relations, just simple tables).

In my Project's `App_Data` directory there is an (empty) mdf file called `trans.mdf`.

When I select  `"Generate database from model"` in the ADO.NET model, I can select my `trans.mdf` in the dialog.

It then builds the ddl and sql file.

The next step then is to execute the generated `.sql` file. And here I'm totally lost. When I select upload, there comes an authentication box from sql server 2008. And finally it tells me that the connection failed.

How can I execute the `.sql` in the `trans.mdf`?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

this video shows how to generate the needed sql statements and then connect to a SQL 2008 to get things going. [**Creating an Entity Data Model the Model-First Way**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628199.aspx).

Comment: Hi,the problem is, that i know how to publish to a .dbo file in VS, but not how to publish to a .mdf file in VS.

Comment: this is the same question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402260/edmx-populating-mdf